# What really happens internally when an update happens on a record with indexed column in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I know that when a table has indexed column(s), sql server duplicates the data of these columns so that it can be accessed fast without looking through every record. And if the index is covered with other columns then all these included columns are also stored along with the indexed columns.

So, I am assuming when an update happens on any of the indexed columns or included columns then it is obvious that the update should happen in both the actual record location and the index location. This point looks interesting to me because if a table is expected to have more updates than searches, then wouldn't it be overhead to have the index? I wanted to confirm on this and also would like to know the internals on what actually happens behind the screen when a update happens.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have it correct.  There is a trade-off when adding indexes.  They have the potential to make selects faster, but they will make updates/inserts/deletes slower.

Comment: Not always .. update/delete with a WHERE condition will also benefit from indexes, if the column included in WHERE have index on it.

Comment: Yes I agree, having Indexed column(s) in WHERE clause will help to identify the record very fast. But it also has to update the data in both the locations which I am referring to an overhead in my actual post. However it all depends on how frequently the column(s) is updated and queried. No direct thumb rule I believe.

Answer (score 0):

When you design an index, consider the following database guidelines:

- Large numbers of indexes on a table affect the performance of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and MERGE statements because all indexes must be adjusted appropriately as data in the table changes. For example, if a column is used in several indexes and you execute an UPDATE statement that modifies that column's data, each index that contains that column must be updated as well as the column in the underlying base table (heap or clustered index).
- Avoid over-indexing heavily updated tables and keep indexes narrow, that is, with as few columns as possible.
- Use many indexes to improve query performance on tables with low update requirements, but large volumes of data. Large numbers of indexes can help the performance of queries that do not modify data, such as SELECT statements, because the query optimizer has more indexes to choose from to determine the fastest access method.
- Indexing small tables may not be optimal because it can take the query optimizer longer to traverse the index searching for data than to perform a simple table scan. Therefore, indexes on small tables might never be used, but must still be maintained as data in the table changes.

For more information have a look at the below link:-

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095(v=sql.110).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
Now moving forward, its clear that we need to understand how update intensive and query intensive the table is to measure the necessity of the Indexing and its effect on performance. So, do we have any tools (apart from sql profiler) or ways that helps us identify how many updates the table (otherwise columns) has got or how many queries does it got on specific amount of time?